# jquery dropdown hide when click inside

Tags: jquery, typo3, dropdownbox

I'm new to jQuery, so maybe this is an easy question, but i havent found a good answer till now. Maybe i havent even found the right keywords to search for...

I have an dropdown login form. I use it in typo3. 
The problem is: any click inside the loginform hides/toggle the drobdownbox.
Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var button = $('#loginButton');
                var box = $('#loginBox');
                var form = $('#loginForm');
                button.removeAttr('href');
                button.mouseup(function(login) {
                    box.slideToggle();
                    button.toggleClass('active');
                });
                form.mouseup(function() {
                    return false;
                    });
                $(document).mouseup(function(login) {
                    if(!($(login.target).parents('#loginButton').length > 0)) {
                        button.removeClass('active');
                        box.hide();
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
```

Maybe someone can help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: Hi tahnks a lot for answer So iám very new in jquery i tried to provide a JSFiddle (sorry if it wrong. my first time!)

Comment: forgot the link: http://jsfiddle.net/9bWDN/

Comment: those `id`s you defined in your script the `loginButton, loginBox and loginForm` they are not found.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like that:

```
    $('selector').mouseenter(function(){

    //do something when mouse is over
    }).mouseleave(function(){

    //do something when mouse out
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

from the jquery docs:
The mouseup event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer is over the element, and the mouse button is released.

I am guessing: Do you want to use the click-event handler here?!

```
button.click(function() {
    box.slideToggle();
    button.toggleClass('active');
});
```

Here you are binding to ALL mouseup events happening on your typo3 site.
Including those above the loginForm!! So it will hide your form on any mouseup

```
$(document).mouseup(function(login) {
    if(!($(login.target).parents('#loginButton').length > 0)) {
        button.removeClass('active');
        box.hide();
    }
});
```

U might want to try this one:

```
$(document).bind("mouseup",function(e){
    console.log(e.target)
})
```

e.target will tell you above which div the mouse was released.
U might want to check something like this:

```
$(document).mouseup(function(login) {
   if(login.target.id == "loginForm"){return false}

    if(!($(login.target).parents('#loginButton').length > 0)) {
        button.removeClass('active');
        box.hide();
    }
});
```

good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I used without

Comment: button.removeClass('active');
                        box.hide(); and it works